# AWS Amplify Google auth user not redirected back

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I'm trying to implement Google auth in a React native app using AWS Amplify. I've installed Amplify in my app and also installed Auth.

I have this client in Google apis: [image]

Authorised javascript origin:

`https://inventory053721f5-053721f5-develop.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com`

Authorised redirect uri:

`https://inventory053721f5-053721f5-develop.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse`

aws-exports.js:

```
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "eu-west-1",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "***",
    "aws_cognito_region": "eu-west-1",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "***",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "***",
    "oauth": {
        "domain": "***",
        "scope": [
            "phone",
            "email",
            "openid",
            "profile",
            "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
        ],
        "redirectSignIn": "inventory://",
        "redirectSignOut": "inventory://",
        "responseType": "code"
    },
    "federationTarget": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
};


export default awsmobile;
```

My `App.tsx` looks like this:

```js
import React, {FunctionComponent} from 'react';
import Amplify, {Auth} from 'aws-amplify';
import {Button} from 'react-native';
import config from '../../aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(config);

export interface AppProps {}

const App: FunctionComponent<AppProps> = () => {
  return <Button title={'Login'} onPress={() => Auth.federatedSignIn()} />;
};

export default App;
```

A video of what happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz9TM.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After setting up Amplify Auth and configuring your [social provider](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#social-provider-setup), you also have to set up [linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) so that your app can handle the callback from the web browser back to your app:

1. Note the value that you entered for the 'redirect signin uri' when you ran `amplify add auth` (such as `myapp:\\`).
2. For apps made using react-native-cli (rather than Expo) on iOS, open the Xcode project (in the ios folder, rnamplify.xcworkspace). Then open `info.plist` as source code and add the following:

```xml
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>myapp</string>
    </array>
  <dict>
</array>
```

3. For apps made using react-native-cli (rather than Expo) on Android, in Android Studio open android/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml and add the following `intent-filter`:

```xml
<intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="myapp" />
</intent-filter>
```

If your app was made with Expo, rather than with react-native-cli, then you wouldn't do steps 2 and 3 above. Instead open your `app.json` file and add the `scheme` key value pair to the "expo" property:

```
{
  "expo": {
   "scheme": "myapp"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I'll surely look this answer up every now and then =)

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be your situation exactly. If you are using the amplify CLI make sure that your redirect signin and signout URIs are set up properly.

You can adjust this by running `amplify update auth`